# pointing Linux DNS server from one sub domain to another subdomain

Tags: dns, domain

I have DNS server to my domain `abc.com`.

Need to point my sub domain `xx.abc.com` to another subdomain `xx.def.com`. As it's hosted in `xx.def.com`, I will get any IP, so they will provide only subdomain name `xx.def.com`. Will it possible to point my subdomain to other subdomain instead of IP in DNS record?

Comment: ... or if you want *all* the records for a subdomain pointed elsewhere, there's also the `DNAME` record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are mentioning different domains **abc.com** & **def.com**, you use web server redirection of `xx.abc.com` to `xx.def.com`. For example the below sample syntax is used to do redirection in Apache server:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
        ServerName xx.abc.com
        Redirect Permanent / xx.def.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This will redirect all request coming from xx.abc.com to xx.def.com.

Comment: It worked with the web server redirection.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a [CNAME record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record). Exact syntax and details will depend on your software, but basically in place of writing something like this:

```
xx.abc.com. A 192.0.2.1
```

…you'll write something like this:

```
xx.abc.com. CNAME xx.def.com.
```

Comment: Will try with CNAME, Will it be faster than A record?

Comment: No, it's bound to be slower than A record because the resolver has to make an additional lookup to find out the address `xx.def.com` points to. Fortunately, this is a common thing, DNS has TTL fields, DNS software has caches—overall, the performance hit will be negligible.

Comment: Mentioning CNAME to different domain `def.com` is not working.. As we have frequent changes in the IP address...